# How does openshift deal with damaged hardware?

Tags: openshift

Are gears sometimes migrated (restarted?) between nodes when the nodes need maintainance, restarts or OS upgrades? Do nodes simply not go down, because fans, hard drives, RAM and CPUs are hotswapped?

How often should I expect my gears to be restarted (if at all)? For example, on EC2 where the hardware is inexpensive, the official figure is (used to be?) 3 months.

I know that there is no official  promise of uptime, but what has the historical record been?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenShift is built on Amazon EC2.  We can migrate gears to different nodes if needed.

Comment: I assume migrating a gear to a different node involves restarting it?

Comment: Correct, Gurgeh, necessarily.